# p Values for FUN="coef" in bootstrapLavaan

Tags: r, p-value, statistics-bootstrap, coefficients, r-lavaan

Suppose I have a lavaan model:

```
fit='
    #Structural model
    var1=~item1+item2+item3
    var2=~item1+item2+item3
    var3=~item1+item2+item3

    #Path model
    var3~var2
    var2~var1
    '
```

I then use sem to calculate:

```
    example=lavaan::sem(fit, data)
```

Now I want to apply bootstrapLavaan as such:

```
    boot.example=bootstrapLavaan(example, FUN="coef")
```

When I analyse the object using...

```
    summary(boot.example)
```

... I am only given values for the coefficients such as the means, medians, min, max, etc. Is there some way to get *p* values for these coefficients?

Comment: If your hull hypothesis is that the coef equal zero then `t(rbind(apply(boot.example, 2, quantile, 
      c(0.025, 0.975)),2* pmin(colMeans(boot.example > 0) , colMeans(boot.example < 0))))` will give 95% CI's ans p-values

Comment: Great, that works as you predicted! Thanks so much. Is there anything I could add there to get the standard errors as well?

Comment: And also (I might be pushing it here), to get the standardized mean coefficients?

Comment: Yet another question (sorry) - is there a way to make the p values show more decimal places?

Comment: re 1.: you should be able to work this out ;), 2.  perhaps rerun the sem with std.ov=TRUE, 3. to get more decimal places, you will need more bootstrap samples (if you use R=1000, you can only get 1/1000 = 4 decimal places).

Comment: So if I have R=250, will I get at least 2 decimal places?

Comment: Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Well it depends on how many resamples meet the condition `colMeans(boot.example > 0)` , as if there are 25 out of 250, you will get a p-value of 0.1, but you could get up to three (ps: previous comment should have been 1/1000 = 3 decimal places)